# How to determine if an IInterface descendant have a property?

Tags: delphi, generics, interface, delphi-2010, delphi-xe

I have a lot of interfaces as a result of importing an type library. So, the interfaces are like this:

```
  ISomeCollection = dispinterface
    ['{6592E851-3D65-4D04-B5F3-B137667B816A}']
    procedure Remove(Identifier: OleVariant); dispid 2;
    function Add(Name: OleVariant; DatabaseType_ID: OleVariant): ERSModel; dispid 3;
    property _NewEnum: IUnknown readonly dispid -4;
    property Item[Identifier: OleVariant]: ERSModel readonly dispid 4;
    property _Item[Identifier: OleVariant]: ERSModel readonly dispid 0; default;
    property Count: Integer readonly dispid 1;
  end;
```

`_NewEnum` is a idiom for Visual Basic `for-each` loop statement consumption ( it's exactly like Delphi's `for-in`) of COM collection of objects - despite the declaration of being IUnknown, it's really an `IEnumVARIANT` interface. Since it's the only way to enumerate the collection' items, I got around it with:

```
{This class have just this class function} 
class function TVariantUtils.GetAs<T>(pModeloOleVar: OleVariant): T;
begin
  Result := (T(IUnknown(pModeloOleVar)));
end;
```

Use:

```
var 
  EnumColecction: IEnumVariant;
  // TEnumeratorObjects: This is a generic class to implement an enumerator over
  // an IEnumVARIANT interface
  ListOfSubObjects: TEnumaretorObjects; 
begin
  ...
  EnumCollection := TVariantUtils.GetAs<IEnumVariant>(Object.SomeCollection._NewEnum);
  ListOfSubObects := TEnumeratorObjects<ItemofSomeCollection>.Create(EnumCollection);
  ...
End;
```

The constructor receives an IEnumVariant parameter. What I want is create an constructor
that receive IInterface and determine if the ISomeCollection have an _NewEnum property of 
IUnknown type - and do the above code once.
I don't know the name or the GUID of the interface on compile-time.

Obs: the delphi-xe tag is because I want to know the mechanism even if works only on Delphi XE 
(even if I need to buy an Starter Edition just for this).
I use D2010.

**EDIT:**
My attempt using RTTI (it compiles but doesn't work):

```
constructor TEnumeratorVariant<T>.Create(pEnumeraVariante: IInterface);
var
  EnumVar: IEnumVariant;
  Contexto: TRttiContext;
  InfoTipo: TRttiType ;
  PropInfo: TRttiProperty;
  pTipo: PTypeInfo;
begin
  Contexto.Create;
  pTipo := TypeInfo(pEnumeraVariante);
  InfoTipo := Contexto.GetType(TypInfo(pEnumeraVariante));
  PropInfo := InfoTipo.GetProperty('_NewEnum');
  if Assigned(PropInfo) then
  begin
    Supports(PropInfo.GetValue(pEnumeraVariante), IEnumVariant, EnumVar);
    Create(EnumVar);
  end;
  Contexto.Free;
  PropInfo.Free;
  InfoTipo.Free;
end;
```

Comment: does delphi have reflection? I think this is the way to do it in other languages.

Comment: Yes, Delphi have an similar concept called RTTI. My last edit have my attempt with it.....

Comment: When you say doing it with RTTI doesn't work, what doesn't it do?

Comment: @Mason: I'm not saying it doesn't work. I'm saying that *in the way I coded it* it doesn't work... So I want to know what is the right path - or even if doesn't exist a right path...

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Also, since it seems you're dealing with COM dual interfaces, you could probably use standard COM `IDispatch` method to retrieve the value of a property with the dispid -4.

Comment: Your original code is *way* more complicated than it needs to be. You call `_NewEnum` and get an `IUnknown`. You implicitly convert it to an `OleVariant` when you pass it to `GetAs`, and in that function you type-cast that *back* to `IUnknown` before casting it (unsafely) to the interface type you really want. Delphi has supported a *direct* way of doing that since version 3. Use the `as` operator: `EnumCollection := Object.SomeCollection._NewEnum as IEnumVariant`.

Comment: @TOndrej: If I knew the IID would be easy to use IDispatch.GetTypeInfo or something like that.

Comment: @Rob: That's not the point here, Rob. I know I could do that. What I don't know how to do is: given an IDispatch descendant passed as parameter, how to detect if it have an _NewEnum property.

Comment: @Fabricio: You should use `IDispatch.Invoke`. Which IID are you talking about?

Comment: @TObjdrej:I confused GetTypeInfo with GetIdOfnames - which requires you know the GUID (IID) of the IDispatch.

Comment: @TOndrej: and Invoke also needs IID.

Comment: @Fabricio: Invoke only needs IID_NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the standard `IDispatch` method (not tested, you may need to tweak it):

```
function GetEnumerator(const Disp: IDispatch): IEnumVariant;
var
  DispParams: TDispParams;
  ExcepInfo: TExcepInfo;
  Status: Integer;
  VarResult: OleVariant;
begin
  Result := nil;
  FillChar(DispParams, SizeOf(DispParams), 0);
  FillChar(ExcepInfo, SizeOf(ExcepInfo), 0);
  Status := Disp.Invoke(DISPID_NEWENUM, GUID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, DispParams, @VarResult, @ExcepInfo, nil);
  if Succeeded(Status) then
    Result := IUnknown(VarResult) as IEnumVariant
  else
    DispatchInvokeError(Status, ExcepInfo);
end;
```

Comment: BTW, this is exactly what the code in Rob's comment `EnumCollection := Object.SomeCollection._NewEnum as IEnumVariant` does. But by writing it out like here you could change it not to raise an exception but instead return `True` or `False` to indicate if the property exists and getting its value succeeded or not.

Comment: Also, if you insist on accessing the property by name '_NewEnum' instead of its dispid (-4), you can first call `GetIDsOfNames` to get the `dispid` and then continue with that like above.

Comment: please change @Result to @VarResult. Thank you very much, it's perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track.  Delphi's RTTI can find methods of an interface, but the interface has to generate RTTI for those methods.  It doesn't do that by default; you have to enable it.  Put a `{$M+}` directive at the top of your type library import unit and it should work.